# No me imprime argumentos en la misma línea

Tags: c++

Hola a todos estoy trabajando en un programa de una mini shell, el problema que tengo es al leer los espacios de que se le introducen, mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void prompt(){
  cout << "mini-shell$ " << flush;
}

bool read_command(){
  string line;
  locale loc;
  char c;
  int length;

  getline(cin, line);

  if (line == "exit" || line == "quit"){
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ){
    c = line[i];
    if (isspace(c, loc)) c = '\n';
    cout << c << endl;
  }
  return true;
}

int main(){

  while( true ){
    prompt();
    if( !read_command() ) return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando imprimo los argumentos me los imprime uno por uno, por ejemplo si introduzco `ls` me imprime primero la l y después la s he probado con quitarle el `endl` pero me imprime `lsmini-shell$` y yo lo que busco es que me imprima sólo el comando algo como:
`ls`
`mini-shell$`
De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema.

Normal, a cada vuelta del bucle que examina la línea pones un salto de línea:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ){
  c = line[i];
  if (isspace(c, loc)) c = '\n';
  cout << c << endl;
  //           ^^^^ <--- salto de linea
}
```

Con el código anterior, si el comando es `ls -t` el bucle hará lo siguiente:

Primera vuelta

- ¿`'l'` es espacio?: no. No hace nada.
- Imprime `l` seguido de `endl`.

Segunda vuelta

- ¿`'s'` es espacio?: no. No hace nada.
- Imprime `s` seguido de `endl`.

Tercera vuelta

- ¿`' '` es espacio?: si. Substituye   por `\n`.
- Imprime `\n` seguido de `endl`.

Cuarta vuelta

- ¿`'-'` es espacio?: no. No hace nada.
- Imprime `-` seguido de `endl`.

Quinta vuelta

- ¿`'t'` es espacio?: no. No hace nada.
- Imprime `t` seguido de `endl`.

#### Solución.

Supongo que quieres un salto de línea sólo si el carácter es un espacio, prueba esto:

```
for (char c : line){
  std::cout << (isspace(c, loc) ? '\n': c);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero aún me imprime algo como `lsmini$shell`

Comment: Pues he hecho una prueba y [a mi me imprime bien](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hy8Mto0gW0v8QaFJ).

Comment: Si ya vi amigo es que faltaba agregar un espacio al final, muchas gracias.